# What does the "QueryDeviceInformationVolume" operation in Process Monitor mean?

Tags: sysinternals, process-monitor, procmon

Seeing an operation called "QueryDeviceInformationVolume" in a SysInternals Process Monitor log when I start a desktop application. Simply trying to get some details about this operation and what it means.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The default procmon settings use friendly names for the event operations.  If you go to `Filter > Enable Advanced Output` it will use a "less-friendly/more "googleable" name.  You can see a full list of operations by opening the filter `CTRL+L` and choosing `Operation` `is` and clicking the dropdown box.  The dropdown will display whichever version (friendly vs less-friendly) depending on if `Enable Advanced Output` is checked or not.